# Read data on one iOS Device from another using Core NFC framework

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-nfc

Is it possible to establish certain type of data transfer like sharing contact or any other info using CoreNFC framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc) states, the Core NFC framework can only be used to detect tags and read messages, it cannot be used to publish messages.

Comment: true, as of today's date it's not possible. Thanks